# Adding Inputs to a Form Dynamically Via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I'm fixing up a form that had a series of areas with two or three duplicate inputs for things like employer name, position, etceteras. I thought it would be easier to just dynamically add them with an onclick button but I am having two major problems: (1) When the onclick event create a new line of inputs the label attributes seems to abandon their css and (2) When you click into the input of the form the label should raise up, but the inputs no longer raise their respective labels.

My questions are (1) What is required to amend the css to keep the labels relative to their inputs and (2) Why/How are the inputs working in the first level of inputs and then not the second?  Also, how can I fix this?

Any help would be great!

I've recreated the problem in a minor way in the code pen below. If you click inside the inputs you'll understand what I mean by "raising."

CodePen Example : http://codepen.io/theodore_steiner/pen/WGOaAR

```
HTML:

 <p class="subtitleDirection">Please list your employment histroy in chronological order, beginning with your current position (Limit of Three)</p>

 <div class="clearFix"></div>

 <div id="employmentHistory">    

     <div class="input-group" id="employment-history-1">

         <input type="text" name="job_1" />
     <label class="schoolBoard">School Board</label>

     <input type="text" name="position_1" />
     <label class="position">Position</label>   

         <input type="text" name="years_1" />
     <label class="years">Years</label>

     <button type="button" id="add_job()" onclick="addJob()" value="+">+</button>
     </div>
</div><!--end of employmentHistory Div-->

CSS:

input
{
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid #21a1e1;
  margin: 15px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 320px;
    float: left;
}

.input-group label
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 17px;
  top: 42px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 17.5px;
  color: #999;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.input-group input:focus+label,
.input-group input.has-value+label {
  top: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #aaa;
}

input:focus,
input:active
{
  outline: none;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"]
{
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b3c1cc;
}

.input-group
{
  position: relative;
}

#teaching-experience-years input
{
    margin-left: 70px;
}

#teaching-experience-years label
{
    left: 421px;
}

#employment-history-1 input
{
    width: 220px;
    float: left;
}

#employment-history-1 label.position
{
    left: 265px;
}

#employment-history-1 label.schoolBoard
{
    left: 15px;
}

#employment-history-1 label.years
{
    left: 514px;
}

JS:


var i = 1;

function addJob()
{
    if( i <= 3 )
    {
        i++;
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = '<div class="input-group" id="employment-history-1"><label class="schoolBoard">School Board</label><input type="text" name="job_'+i+'"><label class="position">Position</label><input type="text" name="position_'+i+'"><label class="years">Years</label><input type="text" name="years_'+i+'"><button type="button" id="add_job()" onclick="addJob()" value="+"></button></div>';

        document.getElementById("employmentHistory").appendChild(div);
    }
};
```

Comment: Sorry for any confusion, please see edits.

Comment: too much work to do to produce complete answer. put your labels and inputs into shared `div`, place those 4 div's inside `input-group` using flex. make every `div` relative, place each label absolutely related to the div. and in JS you can `appendChild(div.firstElementChild);` instead of `appendChild(div);`